# Update Statement from POST Multiple Rows Not Updating

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that is in a while loop so there can be numerous rows.  I have added [] to the name as I am aware it won't update if the name is the same for each row input.  This a short snippet of the row of inputs I have:

```
<td><input type='hidden' name='rowID[]' value='$rowID'>$date</td>
<td width='70'>$billable</td><td width='100'><input value='$details[]' type='text' name='details[]' style='padding:2px;' size='15'></td>
<td width='50'><input value='$parking' type='text' name='parking[]' value='0.00' style='padding:2px;' size='7'></td>
<td width='75'><input value='$mileage' type='text' value='0.00' name='mileage[]' style='padding:2px;' size='10'></td>
<td width='75'><input value='$taxis' type='text' value='0.00' name='taxi[]' style='padding:2px;' size='10'></td><td width='50'>
```

This form then gets processed on another page using:

```
foreach ($_POST['rowID'] as $index => $id) {
    $sql = "UPDATE b_expense_report SET DETAILS = '".$_POST['details'][$index]."', 
    PARKING = '".$_POST['parking'][$index]."', 
    MILEAGE = '".$_POST['mileage'][$index]."', 
    TAXIS = '".$_POST['taxi'][$index]."'
    WHERE ID = '".$_POST['rowID']."'";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
    {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
}
header('Location: mywebsite.com');
```

If I were to do it without the [] then it just updates one row.  I want it to update all rows that are changed.  Currently since I added the [] its not updating anything.

Please let me know where I am going wrong.

Comment: At first, you are updating all records in the table `b_expense_report`, because you are missing `WHERE` clausue...

Comment: what sql does it generate? are you getting the die?

Comment: Sorry I only took a snippet of the code to get my problem across and missed off the where clause.  It runs through the script and redirects to the end but nothing gets updated.

Comment: Well, you're using `$_POST['rowID']` in both your foreach and your WHERE. At least one of those is wrong.

Comment: You are passing the array of rowID's to the where. `WHERE ID = '".$_POST['rowID']."'";` should be `WHERE ID = '".$_POST['rowID'][$index]."'";` or `WHERE ID = '".$id."'";`

Comment: Literally a schoolboy error there.  Thank you Mic.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looping over the same query over and over again, use prepared statements. It also sanitizes your input against SQL injection, which you are not doing at all. Totally untested off the top of my head code:

```
$sql = "UPDATE b_expense_report SET DETAILS=?, PARKING=?, MILEAGE=?, TAXIS=? WHERE ID=?";
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($con, $sql);
mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt, "sssss", $details, $parking, $mileage, $taxi, $id);

foreach ($_POST['rowID'] as $index => $id) {
    $details = $_POST['details'][$index];
    $parking = $_POST['parking'][$index];
    $mileage = $_POST['mileage'][$index];
    $taxi = $_POST['taxi'][$index];
    if (!mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt)) {
        die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
}
```